# How this function: (function(){}()) works?

Tags: javascript

I am reading some question where i find this code, it seems to be easy but i can't understand how this function:`(function() {} ())` works.

Please help me to understand that how the value of `var foo=6` and `bar=9` is only consider in `bar=bar+foo`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        var foo = 6;
        bar = 10;
        (function () {
            var foo = 5;
            bar = 9;
        }())
        bar = bar + foo;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Final value is " + bar;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is known as IIFE. Read here. http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 1):

That's a mix of some pretty bad variable usage, particularly the use of "undeclared" `bar`.

Basically, your global scope has 2 variables, `foo` & `bar`. At first they're initialized to 6 & 10 respectively. Then, a function is called that declares it own `foo` variable and sets that to 5. It also sets the global `bar` to 9. So now the global values are 6 & 9. The sum of these is then 15.

Answer (score 0):

Since

```
var foo = 5;
```

has the `var` declaration, it's a local variable. The assignment has no effect on the `foo` variable outside the function. The global variable continues to have the value `6`.

```
bar = 9;
```

doesn't have a `var` declaration, so it's just an assignment. Since the variable isn't declared locally within the function, this assigns the global variable, so the global variable now has the value `9`.

When you add the two global variables afterward, you get `9 + 6 = 15`.